# Èxport DXF from shapefile with layer styles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dxf, os-mastermap

I have Mastermaps 3 layers with layer styles on QGIS. This is exported with `Project -> Import/ Export -> Export project to DXF` with the following settings;

[image]

However when this is imported to AutoCAD the styles cannot be seen.

[image]

When tried with `Symbology mode` - `Symbol layer symbology` and `Feature symbology` the DXF file shows nothing when it is imported to AutoCAD.

[image]
Can you please help me to to export shapefile with layer style to DXF?

Comment: I think you have to select the field used for symbology in the "Output layer attribute" column (in your first picture it's in the white rectangle with the list of the layer)

Comment: @J.R i did tried that but the output of that does not show anything on AutoCAD. I have updated the question with a print screen with that settings.

Comment: Maybe your symbology is too complex for this tool, or it as something to do with symbology scale (your is set to 1/1000000 but you seem to work at a much bigger scale), anyway you will find more info on the export here https://www.qgis.ch/fr/projets/export-dxf (there are info on supported symbology type)

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but does AutoCAD 'do' styles at all? My colleagues only ever use plain black&white, so I only ever expect to be able to export Mastermap topographic line data - unstyled.

Comment: Yes, you can export the layer styling into AutoCAD and it is working well for me now.  @Rostranimin it would have been nice to check more details before commenting as  'Silly'. I will leave you to decide to whom that word be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry @Shana - I was entirely meaning that *my* question might be silly, definitely not yours. Perhaps a clumsy form of words, a bit too conversational... Actually if you could answer this question (with whatever solution you discovered) I'd be really keen to know how you do this. I can inform the AutoCAD 'experts' in my office who clearly don't know this is possible.

Comment: @Shana I know it may sound silly, but have you tried zoom to extents command in AutoCAD? The file looks empty when opened, and its normal, cause the elements are placed in file according to choosen coordinate system, and you always have to zoom out to them.